# Can you add a sprite kit particle emitter to the background of a UIViewController?

Tags: ios

I'm new to sprite kit game development and I was wondering if it's possible to add a particle emitter to a UIViewController. I want to have buttons on the screen along with the particle emitter for an app idea I have which is the problem. There is no built in button object for SKScene, so I decided maybe it would be better to add a particle emitter to a UIViewController class instead. Is it possible to make a particle emitter in the background and to place buttons on top of it that way?

Answer (score 1):

Is there a specific reason you want to use SpriteKit for this? If you just want to integrate particle effects in a UIViewController, look into using a view and adding a CAEmitterLayer and CAEmitterCell.

They work great without using any of SpriteKit, and performance is good.

Answer (score 1):

One of the good features about SpriteKit is the easiness of the implementation with UIKit:

**Create a SKScene subclass:**

```
//ParticleScene.h
#import <SpriteKit/SpriteKit.h>

@interface ParticleScene : SKScene

@property SKEmitterNode *emitter;

@end



//ParticleScene.m
#import "ParticleScene.h"

@implementation ParticleScene

-(instancetype)initWithSize:(CGSize)size{
    if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [self addEmitterNode];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void) addEmitterNode{
    SKEmitterNode *emitter = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"SpriteKitParticleEmitter" ofType:@"sks"]];
    emitter.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), self.frame.size.height);
    [self addChild:emitter];
}

@end
```

**Create SpriteKitParticleEmitter.sks**
Top menu -> File / New / File... / (Resource) SpriteKit Particle File

Here you can modify the emitter as you want.

**Add emitter to your UIViewController**
You can add a UIView to your Storyboard and set it's subclass to SKView, or you can add the SKView programatically:

Add in `-(void) viewDidLoad` method:

```
SKView *spriteKitView = self.particleView; // Defined on storyboard
//Use SKView *spriteKitView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame] to create it programatically and then [self.view addSubView:view];
spriteKitView.showsFPS = NO;
spriteKitView.showsNodeCount = NO;
spriteKitView.allowsTransparency = YES; //Prevents this view to show as a black square
spriteKitView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

SKScene *scene = [JPParticleScene sceneWithSize:view.bounds.size];
scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;

[view presentScene:scene];
```

If you use a Storyboard, just place `self.spriteKitView` behind your `UIButtons`.

Comment: What's a JPParticleScene?